# JAVA DAO/Hibernate: persist & retrieve generic hashmap into/from Database field

Tags: java, database, oracle, hibernate, dao

I'm new to hibernate and I would like to store a hashmap of primitive objects into a oracle DB field.
In fact, depending on the process, different keys are put inside the map so I cannot create a DB field for each key (as I don't know them upfront. also I would like to put all the information in a single DB field).
Is it possible to do so? should data be compressed?

Comment: Collections in Java can't hold primitives. So you want to store all your data in a single column?

Comment: yes. basically my data is in a HashMap<String, Object>() whih contains int,String,boolean,BigDecimal and I would like to store them in a single column